# Disable Null Textboxes inside While Loop

Tags: jquery, textbox, while-loop

I have a while loop with fetching records from my database... each record will be displayed inside the while loop... some of this texboxes may contain a value of may be null

Code:

```
    while ($imps_row1 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt_line_util3,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='op[]'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' readonly name='pid[]' class='txtDis3' value='".$imps_row1['pid_code']."'/></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' readonly  class='txtDis1' value='".$imps_row1['path']."' name='path[]'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' readonly  class='txtDis1' value='".$imps_row1['id_code']."' name='cmisg[]'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' readonly class='txtDis1' value='".$imps_row1['description']."' ></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text'  class='txtDis' name='txt1[]' value='".$imps_row1['qualified_borrower']."'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text'  class='txtDis' name='txt2[]' value='".$imps_row1['allowed_borrower']."'></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
```

How can i disable textboxes containing null values using jQuery/Javascript..

I used this jquery code but nothing happened

```
$(function(){
$('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
  if ($(this).val() === '') {
  $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
  });
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a loop, just this ([**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/6ZAcN/))

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="text"][value=""]').prop('disabled', 1);
});
```

All `textbox` that has `value=''` will be disabled.